# Why is refreshing my Angular 6 project on S3/Cloudfront causing errors?

Tags: xml, angular, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am having an issue with my Angular 6 project hosted on an S3 bucket with Cloudfront. Every time I refresh, the project seems to be lost and I am redirected to a page that says:
[image]
What could be causing this? When I refresh on my local server, I am simply logged out and redirected to the login page. I thought this might be a problem with my S3 bucket settings, so I uploaded to the project that I knew was configured correctly (I had an Angular 5 project in there that didn't have the refresh problem). But, the same thing happened so it seems it is something within my project.

Could it be how I compile the files? I am using 'ng build'

Any help is appreciated! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities:

(1) If your Angular on AWS S3 is client-side-rendered then every time you refresh your website your browser will send a request to AWS CloudFront to acquire the file from AWS S3.

eg. Reloading https://yourdomain.com/contact will actually sending a request to AWS S3 bucket > 'contact' directory > index.html, which is not existing because the page you're viewing is purely generated at client side.

Solution: CloudFront distribution > Error Pages > Create Custom Error Response > Create your custom responses for Error 400, 403, 404.

For example, an custom error response for Error 400:

```
HTTP Error Code: 400 Bad Request
Error Caching Minimum TTL: 300 
Customize Error Response: Yes
Response Page Path: /index.html
HTTP Response Code: 200 OK
```

(2) If your Angular is server-side-rendered, then you have to use your AWS S3 endpoint as the 'Origin Path Name' instead of the autocomplete from AWS dropdown list. For more details, you can refer to: [Prerender Angular and Host It on AWS S3](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/prerender-angular-and-deploy-it-as-a-static-website-on-aws-s3-to-make-it-42-times-faster-115fadcf8614)

Answer (score 2):

I just set index.html to Error document in the static website hosting and it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your AWS S3 project structure is.I am assuming you have given public access to the files (Access Control List) along with the correct Bucket Policy and you have put the build in the root directory.

Make sure that in the bucket properties(static site hosting) you have added index.html for the error document field.

Also make sure to add error pages in your cloudfront distribution, create 2 custom error responses for codes 403 & 404 which point to your index.html and return a response code of 200.

Edit: Here is a link to refer to
https://hackernoon.com/hosting-static-react-websites-on-aws-s3-cloudfront-with-ssl-924e5c134455

Answer (score 0):

Within your s3 bucket, the built files need to have 'public' access

If you've just changed the permissions, it may take a few minutes before the changes are replicated across the s3 availability zones and cloudfront cache reads the new permissions